# Navigation Master-Detail using MvvmCross Forms and Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross, xamarin.forms

I am having some problem in the nagivation between the Master ans Detail Page using MvvmCross Forms, the page opens up in blank.

```
class MasterPage : MasterDetailPage
{
    public MasterPage()
    {

        var masterContentPage = new MasterContentPage();

        masterContentPage.ListView.ItemSelected += (sender, e) => NavigateTo(e.SelectedItem as MasterPageItem);

        Master = masterContentPage;
        Detail = new PaymentMethodsListPage();
    }


    void NavigateTo(MasterPageItem menu)
    {
        Page displayPage = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(menu.TargetType);

        Detail = displayPage;

        IsPresented = false;
    }
}
```

How can I bind my navigation to the ViewModel?

Thanks.